# raise event after multiple selection with ctrl key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-select

Hi,

I want to trigger an event on an element list. The list may have multiple selection. The event should be triggered directly, if user clicks on element without `ctrl` key.
If the user presses `ctrl`+click then, event should be triggered once the selection is done.
I have written my own logic for that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nLSP/). 
I can prevent event from triggering immediately after click with combination of `ctrl`. But I am not getting the idea when to trigger my own function(lets say `alert` here...) ,if there is multiple selection.

Comment: You want like alert with output one,two,three..???

Comment: Yes,If user clicks on element with CTRL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = "";
$(document).ready(function() {

    // bind only click event

    $('ul > li').on('click', function(event) {

        // if ctrl key is press

        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            str = str + $(this).text() + ",";
        } else {
            str = $(this).text();
            alert(str);
            str = '';  // after alert reset the str
        }
    });

    // bind a keyup event
    $(document).on('keyup', function(event) {

        // str is not empty and ctrl key is released
        // show alert
        if(str && !event.ctrlKey) {
            alert(str);
        } 
        str = ''; // after alert reset the str
    });
});​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nLSP/4/)***

#### Note

you don't need to maintain any flag for `ctrl` key press. `event.ctrlKey` will do this for you.

Comment: Well, this one is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onmouseout` event.

Set a flag to check if at least one is selected and if the flag was true, event should trigger your code.

You can also use  `setTimeout`, so when the mouse goes on  tag (onmouseover) your timeout gets deleted and when the mouse goes out of  after something like 1 or 2 seconds event could be triggered. The benefit of this is if the user is still selecting but suddenly moves his/her mouse out, then the code will not be triggered for a few seconds.

**UPDATE, here is an example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var str = '';
            var _ctrlPressed  = false;
            var my_timer;
            var my_flag = false;

            function set_timer(){
                my_timer = setTimeout(selection_end, 2000);
            }

            function reset_timer(){
                clearTimeout(my_timer);
            }

            function selection_end(){
                if(_ctrlPressed && my_flag && str != ''){
                    my_flag = false;
                    alert('Selection is done: ' + str);
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('ul > li').click(function(event){
                    if(event.ctrlKey){
                        _ctrlPressed = true;
                    }else{
                        _ctrlPressed = false;
                    }

                    if(_ctrlPressed){
                        str = str + $(this).text()+",";
                        my_flag = true;
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        str = $(this).text();
                    }
                    alert(str);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul onmouseover="reset_timer();" onmouseout="set_timer();">
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        <ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If he want to select last one first,then ..??